# How to check in django model ManyToManyField is symmetrical,if symmetrical=False?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, model

I'm trying to create a followers system in Django.

`follows = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='follower', symmetrical=False, null=True, blank=True)`

Since the system should not be symmetrical, how can I check that two users follow each other?

I want to have a function within the model, if possible. I might use this function within `limit_choices_to` of another field and some other places.

My initial thought was to add a "friends" field and make it symmetrical, but this can bring other issues later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find an easy solution, that won't require additional models.
Here what I've done:

Creating `Person(models.Model)` is not required, if you have something like `CustomUser(AbstractUser)` implemented. Otherwise `Person` class can be useful in many situations.

`count_` functions are pretty useful, but not required for most of the use cases.

Inside `accounts/models.py` I added:

```
RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING = 1
RELATIONSHIP_BLOCKED = 2
RELATIONSHIP_STATUSES = (
    (RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING, 'Following'),
    (RELATIONSHIP_BLOCKED, 'Blocked'),
)

class Person(models.Model):
     relationships = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='Relationship',
                                           symmetrical=False,
                                           related_name='related_to')

     def get_relationships(self, status):
        return self.relationships.filter(
            to_people__status=status,
            to_people__from_person=self)

    def get_related_to(self, status):
        return self.related_to.filter(
            from_people__status=status,
            from_people__to_person=self)

    def get_following(self):
        return self.get_relationships(RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING)

    def get_followers(self):
        return self.get_related_to(RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING)

    def count_following(self):
        return len(self.get_relationships(RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING))

    def count_followers(self):
        return len(self.get_related_to(RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING))

    def get_friends(self):
        return self.relationships.filter(
            to_people__status=RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING,
            to_people__from_person=self,
            from_people__status=RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING,
            from_people__to_person=self)

    def count_friends(self):
        return len(self.get_friends())

class Relationship(models.Model):
    from_person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='from_people', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    to_person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='to_people', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=RELATIONSHIP_STATUSES)

    def add_relationship(self, person, status):
        relationship, created = Relationship.objects.get_or_create(
            from_person=self,
            to_person=person,
            status=status)
        return relationship

    def remove_relationship(self, person, status):
        Relationship.objects.filter(
            from_person=self,
            to_person=person,
            status=status).delete()
        return
```